# NSButton with two functions

Tags: cocoa, methods, nsbutton

i have a NSButton which uploads a file and parses the response.
I want to implement the following:
When i click on the button he uploads the file and parses the response. While this is happening the buttons title should change from "upload" to "cancel" and when i press on the button again while he is uploading or parsing the process of parsing or uploading should stop.
When the process was canceled or successfully the buttons title should return to "upload" and if i would click the button now he should start with upload and parsing again.
I hope you can imagine what i mean, english isn't my native language ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single action like this.

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {

     NSButton *btn=(NSButton *)sender;

    [btn setTitle:([btn.title isEqualToString:@"Upload"] ? @"Cancel" : @"Upload")];

    if([btn.title isEqualToString:@"Upload"]){
        //Do upload and parsing
    }else{
        //Cancel upload and parsing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All controls have a target and an action. The target is usually some controller object. When your target's action is called (say `-multiPurposeButtonClicked:`), you can change some internal state of your controller (maybe a BOOL called `needsUpload`) and set the sender's (the button's) title or perform some other activities based on this state. That method might call `[self beginProcessingUpload]` or `[self cancelTheWholeThing]` based on whether or not `needsUpload == YES`. When your "upload complete" callback occurs, you can reset the controller's state and use an outlet to the button (maybe `IBOutlet NSButton * uploadButton;`) to reset the title.

It's really up to you how to approach this. More specific questions will get more focused answers.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would have to, when the button is first pressed, create a new thread that uploads and parses the response thing, then change the title of the button and if the button is pressed again then destroy the thread and revert the button's title back, make sure also that, once the thread is done, to revert the status of the button back.

---

** To determine what action should be taken on the button click, just test the handle to the thread to see if it's nil, if so then create a new thread, else terminate and set to nil. (don't forget to set to nil to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

You could re-assign the action of your NSButton to an alternative selector. Say you have two selectors: `upload:(id)sender` and `cancel:(id)sender`.

Initially set up your NIB to call the `upload:` selector. In the `upload:` selector you could then use an outlet (as Joshua mentioned) to change the title of the button to cancel and then change the action:

```
- (IBAction)upload:(id)sender {
    [uploadButton setTitle:@"Cancel"];
    SEL cancelSelector = @selector(cancel:);
    [uploadButton setAction:cancelSelector];

    // Carry out upload actions
}
```

In the `cancel:` selector you can set these back as they were before:

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [uploadButton setTitle:@"Upload"];
    SEL uploadSelector = @selector(upload:);
    [uploadButton setAction:uploadSelector];

    // Carry out cancel actions
}
```

You'll of course have to add extra handling to consider setting the Upload button back when an upload is completed.